# How to monitor a log file and send an alert if it stopped?

Tags: windows, file, powershell, monitoring

Is there a way to monitor a log file and send an alert(email) if the file stopped writing new lines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is the powershell script to achieve required result.
Once script is executed Code will get executed every five minutes unless powershell window is closed, no need to schedule script in task scheduler.

```
$LogFile = "C:\logs\mylogFile.log"
while($true)
{
    $LastWriteTime = (Get-ChildITem $LogFile).LastWriteTime
    $CurrentTime = Get-Date
    $Diff = (New-TimeSpan -Start $LastWriteTime -End $CurrentTime).TotalMinutes
    If($Diff -gt 5)
    {
        #Send Email Alert if file not written from last 5 minutes or Alert That you want
    }

    sleep -Seconds (60*5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer instance like [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from .NET and on the timer handler check the last modified date of your file. You can get the last modified date of a file using [System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5da1572.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) from .NET. If the last modified date is old enough then you can send the alert.

Comment: This is a great idea but actually i have a weak background about coding,  anyone tried to use this idea ? @daniel